# Heroku add record to sqlite

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have just deployed my app to heroku, and after some problems, it seem to work.
But then i try to add a record to an sqlite3 database from the app, it's not working, and isn't redirecting me to '/'.

It's a sinatra app, i have installed all the data mapper dependencies, and the logs doesn't repost errors.
here is the code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'dm-core'  
require 'dm-timestamps'  
require 'dm-validations'  
require 'dm-migrations'
DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/rubrica.db")

class Contatto  
  include DataMapper::Resource  
  property :id, Serial  
  property :fname, Text
  property :lname, Text
  property :phone, Text  
  property :mail, Text
end  

DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!  

get '/' do
    @title = 'Tutti'
  @Contatti = Contatto.all
    erb :home
end

get '/add' do
    @title = 'Aggiungi'
    erb :aggiungi
end

post '/' do
    c = Contatto.new
    c.fname = params[:fname]
c.lname = params[:lname]
c.phone = params[:phone]
c.mail = params[:mail]
c.save
redirect '/'
```

end

and the link
[here](http://rubrica.heroku.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Heroku doesn't use sqlite.  If you specify sqlite as your database of choice, Heroku will do some black magic when it receives the push, and replace the sqlite3 gem with the postgres gem, and then run your application with a postgres database.  So that explains why your `DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/rubrica.db")` call isn't working.

[Read this Heroku doc for more information.](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database)

Upon some further reading of the Heroku docs, it appears that you need to change your call to Datamapper to be as such:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/rubrica.db')
```

Comment: So, I should switch to postgres? and why it can get the existing records?

Comment: @Francesco: Yes, you should switch to PostgreSQL if you're going to deploy to Heroku, it will save you a lot of unnecessary pain and suffering. Develop on top of PostgreSQL 8.3 if you're deploying to a shared database, 9.0 if you're deploying to a dedicated database.

Comment: You can develop on SQLite. If you create an app that does not rely on underlying db details, that's a win. Deploy to a testing place on heroku to check things. It depends I guess on how tricky you want to get with your db tables. Tricky is usually bad, but sometimes it's the only way.